# CSS states on ion-button are not being applied

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to either apply a background color when a `ion-button` has been clicked or to keep the `ion-ripple` after it filled the button with Ionic 4.

I tried to apply custom css states in `global.scss` but it didn't really work as the active state looks like it is quickly removed after you click the button (added and then removed half a second after):

```
ion-button {
    &:active {
        color: red;
    }
    &:visited {
        background-color: black !important; // --background didn't change anything here
    }
}
```

I tried also with `--background-activated` which worked but doesn't have the effect I'm looking for. I want to persist the ripple background after the button has been clicked.

Looked everywhere for the `ion-ripple` configuration but there's not such thing to make it persists. 
A solution would be to use the `ion-ripple` component it-self but I would like to avoid that as it means going through the entire app and replace every `ion-button`...

So how can I get a generic `ion-button` to keep a background-color after it has been clicked ?

Comment: In mobile you can use classnameof button:hover{background:coloryouneed}, hover can be used on mobile and will be removed when user click on other place. So hover will keep applied since there is no mouse to hover normally.

Comment: @MostafaHarb Thanks for the comment, while this might work on mobile, the app is multiplatform and will be used on computer as well :/

Comment: You can add querySelector and add class or remove it on click, so onClick class will be added with background and on unfocus remove the visited class. I thing this better for multiplatform.

Answer (score 1):

You may have seen this too. Looking into the ion-ripple component [source](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/ripple-effect/ripple-effect.tsx) it looks like is has a removeRipple function that removes the ripple after 200 milliseconds. I can't see anywhere that would allow you to add configuration to change that and keep the ripple effect forever.

But maybe using NgClass could be a possible solution. I was thinking something like this...

`home.page.html`

```
<ion-button (click)="clickAction()" [ngClass]="{'clicked':beenClicked}">
  Change Color When Clicked
</ion-button>
```

`home.page.ts`

```
export class HomePage {
  beenClicked: boolean = false;

  clickAction() {
    this.beenClicked = true;
  }

}
```

`home.page.scss`

```
.clicked {
  --background: green;
}
```

You could move the style to the global.scss and make it available everywhere, although you probably still have to have the boolean property in every component unless you have a service or some kind of state management to help keep track of all of your button states for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I guess there is no other real solutions for this other than workarounds then, since the timeout in the ripple looks hardcoded with no control on it. The problem I see with your solution is that if I want to keep the ripple effect on the button, I will probably have some conflicts with the styling... And I will also have to go through the entire app (who is kinda big right now) and modify it.
Elegant solution overall but not really what I'm looking for. Maybe what I want is impossible to do right now :)

Comment: Completely understand. It is also possible to recreate the ripple component using StencilJS and remove the removal timeout. [Josh Morony](https://www.joshmorony.com/) has some great blog posts about StencilJS that you might find helpful. Good luck.